# My optical drive of my laptop keeps popping out

Tags: windows-10, lenovo-laptop, optical-drive

I have Lenovo ThinkPad T420 with Windows 10 on board. Every time I insert the disk into optical drive and close it, drive keeps popping out. I already tried going to the hardware management window and reinstalling it.

Any suggestions on how should I proceed with fixing this issue?

Comment: T420 series has multiple models T420, T420i, T420s and T420si. Which one is yours?

Comment: It's probably [hardware issue](http://www.techsupportforum.com/forums/f149/solved-dvd-drive-keeps-ejecting-all-disks-631521.html). Open the hardware and pressed hard on all cables leading to DVD Drive.

Comment: Is the issue that the drive pops out of the laptop, or the disc pops out of the drive?

Answer (score 1):

We use a lot of T420 in my workplace and I have noticed this problem in most laptops. We are running Windows 7. I think that this could be a hardware issue rather than the *eject* function of Windows coming into play.

**How to verify this:**

- You can verify if this a Windows based issue or not, by using a live USB of some [Linux OS](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/) and see how the disk drive behaves.
- If it the disk drive doesn't pop out it means that it is a Windows based issue.
- If it does pop even on a live USB it is a hardware issue (as guessed).

*Side-note:* Due to security reasons I cannot do this test on my office laptops.